# Only 1 result from JSON loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Could somebody explain how come this is only returning 1 result (there should be 4). Its only returning the most recent post title, where I would like to be getting all the post titles in the category (ID: 121) which in this case is four.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var posturl = "http://www.tropical420.com/api/get_posts/?posts_per_page=-1";

            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: posturl,
                complete: function(){                    
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    var response = data; //JSON.parse(data);

                    //loop through posts
                    for(var i = 0; i != response.posts.length; i++) {

                    //get each element in the array
                    var post = response.posts[i];

                    // post vars
                    var postTitle   = post.title;
                    var postContent = post.content;
                    var postCategory = post.categories[i].id;

                    // output stuff so we can see things


                        if (postCategory == '121') {
                            $("#post").append(postTitle + "<br />").trigger('create');
                        }

                    }

                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                    
                    alert("Error");

                }

            });
         </script>

<div id="post"></div>
```

Comment: Should we guess what your JSON looks like?

Comment: Not a solution, just curious.  Why does your `for` loop do `i != response.posts.length`?  I've always learned it as `i < response.posts.length`.

Comment: @Teemu Following the link, I'm not sure you WANT to know what the json looks like...

Comment: You must add `dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax` options.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Well think about it for a while, when does that become false? Does the < become false on same iteration?

Comment: @Teemu you could just call the url ..

Comment: @AndrewDunai: Unless the URL responds with the correct `Content-type: application/json` header.

Comment: @johnSmith Yes, but questions should also be complete.

Comment: @johnSmith: Actually, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @john Smith not our responsibility

Comment: @sanfor: I realize it's the same... I'm just curious.  I usually see `<` used in loops.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: So? If it yields the same output, what does it matter other than readability? I've also used to write `++i`, still `i++` works too, even though at least on C++ there is might be minor performance difference but semantics are the same when used to increase for loop variable.

Comment: what is `response.posts.length`? How many actually have the `postCategory == '121'`?

Comment: @user12920 Are you sure it gets executed only once? Did you try putting `console.log` in the place where you `append` to div?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Using `!=` instead of `<` in a situation like this is a bad idea, in my opinion. If somehow you had a situation where the counter variable was larger than the total number of items, `!=` would cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you aren't iterating through all the categories, instead you are just referring with the same index as to your posts array. You should iterate all the categories through like this

```
var postCategories= post.categories;

for (var postCategoryIndex in postCategories)
{
    var postCategory = postCategories[postCategoryIndex].id;
    if (postCategory == '121') {
      $("#post").append(postTitle + "<br />").trigger('create');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON returned does indeed include 49 posts, and you would know that if you had tried `console.log(response.posts.length)`

sanfor has pointed out the logic error in your code, but your whole callback function can be written much more cleanly, like this:

```
function (data) {
    data.posts.filter(function (post) {
        return post.categories.filter(function (cat) { return cat.id === '121'; });
    }).forEach(function (post) {
        $("#post").append(post.title + "<br />").trigger('create');
    });
}
```